# Pagination errors in ruby on rails report

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've recently started learning ruby-on-rails and now I've got to the point where I can create something but still not very comfortable with syntax.
In report view,when i paginate to the 2nd page it gives me a error.

But paginations were corrected in yesterday.Today i edited some checkboxes using params.dig method to hold the checkbox values.those values are also need to disply in 2nd page.What's the problem with my controller

This is my view

```
 %br
          .row
            .col-md-3
              = check_box_tag "search_customer_supplier[accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code][]","CUS", params.dig('search_customer_supplier', 'accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code') == "CUS"
              = label_tag "Organizational Customer"
            .col-md-3
              = check_box_tag "search_customer_supplier[accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code][]", "SUP", params.dig('search_customer_supplier', 'accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code') == "SUP"
              = label_tag "Organzational Supplier"
            .col-md-3
              = check_box_tag "search_customer_supplier[accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code][]", "INDCUS", params.dig('search_customer_supplier', 'accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code') == "INDCUS"
              = label_tag "Individual Customer"
            .col-md-3
              = check_box_tag "search_customer_supplier[accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code][]", "INDSUP", params.dig('search_customer_supplier', 'accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code') == "INDSUP"
              = label_tag "Individual Supplier"
```

This is my controller

```
 def customer_supplier_report
    Organization
    Address
    ContactNumber
    refined_query = ""
    if params[:search].present? or params[:excel_report].present?

      search_customer_supplier = params[:search_customer_supplier]

      if params[:organization_children].present? and search_customer_supplier["id"].present?
        organization_id = search_customer_supplier["id"]
        organization = Organization.find(organization_id)
        anchestor_ids = organization.anchestors.map{|o| o[:member].id }
        search_customer_supplier["id"] = "(#{anchestor_ids.join(' OR ')})" if anchestor_ids.any?
      end

      params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'] = params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'].join(" OR ") if params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'].present?

      # puts params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code']

      customer_report = params[:search_customer_supplier].map { |k, v| "#{k}:#{v}" if v.present? }.compact
    else
      customer_report = ["accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code:(CUS OR SUP OR INDCUS OR INDSUP)"]
    end
```

In my browser showing me where are the error lines in controller.Those are,

```
params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'] = params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'].join(" OR ") if params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'].present?
```

This is output errors that i got

NoMethodError in ReportsController#customer_supplier_report

undefined method `join' for "CUS":String Did you mean? JSON

Comment: can you show the value of params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code']

Comment: When i checked in first checkbox. this is the value i got 



======
SUP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because `join()` is the method of `Array class`. But your parameter value is of string type.

ie.

```
[1,2,3].join(' OR ') #=> "1 OR 2 OR 3"
```

but

```
"aasd".join('OR') #=> will throw exception which you are getting.
```

check whether your parameter value is a proper array or not

Comment: ur opinion is correct my parameter value is a string type.How can i fixed this problem.I haven't much knowledge on programming.I' new to programming

Comment: Understand your requirements then try to solve it. If you want to convert a string to array you can do so by methods provided by ruby "a,b,c".split(',') = ['a','b','c']

Comment: I tried that method also.But it gave me some errors.I attached those below with my answer..
@Vishal

Answer (score 0):

Then it came this error output

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGB23.png

this project use elasticsearch to pagination also.i will attach my code below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMSrw.png

Comment: I think you are getting wrong data in your parameter. That's why your query breaks